# ColdFusion: QUERY to JSON

Tags: jquery, json, coldfusion

I have an query, which I want to convert to a JSON object.

Within my Query, there is a String (for example `"0000"` or `"0001"`). Unfortunately, after calling `SerializeJSON`, the String is a number (`0`, `1`, ...).

I get an error when calling the functions with jQuery because the JSON object isn't valid. The quotation marks are fail:

```
{
   "COLUMNS": ["Test1","Test2","Test3"],
   "DATA": [ ["AA ",0000,"testestest"] ]
}
```

I already tried so many things. Can you help me?

Here is my code:

```
<cffunction name="getData" access="remote" returntype="any" returnformat="JSON">
    SQL....

    <cfset result = SerializeJSON(result)>

    <cfreturn result>
</cffunction>
```

Answer (score 5):

This a ColdFusion 9 bug which had been registered in the Adobe ColdFusion (Bug ID 83638). You can upgrade your ColdFusion to ColdFusion 9.0.1 to resolve this issue. You need to just install the hot fix.

Visit the following URL for installing the hot fix.

http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/cumulative-hotfix-1-chf1-coldfusion.html

This fix is already added in ColdFusion 10.

Answer (score 3):

This function might help: http://www.davidosomething.com/blog/fix-cf-serializejson-number-conversion

Alternatively, use this approach:
http://www.ghidinelli.com/2008/12/19/tricking-serializejson-to-treat-numbers-as-strings

You could modify your query so it selects the column and appends some leading whitespace at the same time, e.g.

```
<cfquery>
  SELECT ' ' + Test2 AS yourColumn
```

Answer (score 3):

Although not exactly the same there is [a post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149398/how-can-i-use-angularjs-and-a-serializejson-cfquery) that I asked about serializing a query to json be used with AngularJS that might be helpful